# Jetty 9 Handler Examples?

Tags: java, jetty

I am building my first project with Jetty and I love the amount of control it gives. I'm going to use Jetty 9 but I'm having trouble finding examples of all the different types of handlers and how to use HandlerWrappers, HandlerLists, ServletContextHandler, etc.

Are there any good resources out there with solid examples of these and anything else that might interest me/help me better my implementation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are working on jetty9 documentation here (it is a work in progress):

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/

Documentation can be forked at github if you like to contribute, see the link at the bottom of any page.

Right now jetty itself will be the best example of any of these concepts, and we'll be expanding our embedded examples over the next few months.  These are the current embedded examples.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

Also there are copious examples littered throughout the unit tests of jetty itself.

Comment: Thanks, I've been lost trying to find something like this. I also noticed that some of the links to Jetty 9 documentation are broken on the eclipse site. Thanks again.